# How to pass php config file to Node.js?

Tags: php, node.js

My php config file looks like:

```
define('hostname_con1', 'localhost');
define('database_con1', 'mydatabase');
define('username_con1', 'user');
define('password_con1', 'password');
```

What would be the **"smart"** method to use that in my nodejs application to avoid to define database parameters again in my nodejs application ?

```
var client = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'user',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'mydatabase',
    charset: 'utf8', 
    insecureAuth: true,
});
```

I want to have 1 single config file for all (php and nodejs)

regards

Comment: Make your config file a JSON string and import it?

Comment: I agree with @Crontab's suggestion, both PHP and node have file readers and JSON parsing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the configuration in a format that can be parsed by both languages and is not PHP specific, e.g. JSON, YAML, INI, whathaveyou.

Comment: Not the smart way: But one can also create a `define()` function in js. And then import the php config file.

Comment: Err, yeah, no, please don't. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a common data format that both Node and PHP can process.

Easiest would be to store your data as JSON, and use `json_decode()` in PHP and appropriate code in node to parse it. But you can use any other format (such as yaml, ini, etc) for which there are both PHP and JavaScript parsers.

Comment: Personally I would recommend YAML over JSON for a config file.

Comment: For small config files, I would recommend JSON since both Node and PHP supports it without any other dependencies. For larger config files, YAML is usually much cleaner. Generally I think people are using YAML way to much these days when it's not really needed.